# stream in flutter: static Stream<List<UserModel>>

Tags: flutter, bloc

How can I make this work? I don't know how to code it. Can you help me?I want to take all users from firebase and filter them in a search page

```
  static Stream<List<UserModel>> searchUserFuture({required String query}) {
    query = query.toLowerCase();
    List<UserModel> l;
    _fireStoreUserCollection
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
              
              int matchs = 0;
              UserModel user =
                  UserModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(jsonEncode(doc.data())));
              if (user.name.contains(query) ||
                  user.lastName.contains(query) ||
                  user.level.contains(query) ||
                  user.location.contains(query)) {
                matchs++;
              }
              for (int j = 0; j < user.best.length; j++) {
                if (user.best[j].nameB.contains(query)) {
                  matchs++;
                }
              }
              for (int k = 0; k < user.initial.length; k++) {
                if (user.initial[k].nameI.contains(query)) {
                  matchs++;
                }
                if (user.initial[k].type.contains(query)) {
                  matchs++;
                }
              }
              if (matchs > 0) {
                l.add(user);
              }
              return l;
            }));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you share more details?

The static methods not can access an internal value like `_fireStoreUserCollection`